# Gradient outside of the container and continue inside the container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following snippet :

```css
.test {
  margin-top: 50px; 
  margin-bottom: 50px; 
  padding-bottom:7px;
  background: /* gradient can be an image */
    linear-gradient(
      to left,
      black 0%,
      #FFFFFF 100%
    )
    left
    bottom
    #777
    no-repeat;
  background-size:100% 7px ;/* if linear-gradient, we need to resize it */
}

.test2{
  border-bottom: 7px solid black
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="test2"></div>
</div>
```

And the expect result is as fallow :

[image: result]

The red line is where the container starts. I want to make a gradient from 0% to 100% outside the container and continue inside the container with the black color only. Is this achievable ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the goal or purpose?

Comment: I want to make a separation, the gradient should stop when he meet the container

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try with the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements, here is an example :

https://jsfiddle.net/pierrep/8hdnzgfa/

SCSS :

```
.inside_bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;

  &::before {
    content: '';
    width: 17.5%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, #000);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }

  &::after {
    content: '';
    width: 17.5%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent, #000);
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

CSS :

```
.inside_bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
}

.inside_bar::before {
  content: '';
  width: 17.5%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, #000);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.inside_bar::after {
  content: '';
  width: 17.5%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent, #000);
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use it without SCSS ?

Comment: @executable Yes, I edited my answer to show you SCSS and CSS